# Ionic app auth0 Google sign-in using Google+ App

Tags: ionic-framework, google-signin, auth0

I can't find anywhere on auth0 documentation on how to implement Google+ app based Google sign-in, all I've seen around is the inAppBrowser based approach. Is there any way I can implement Google+ app based login in Ionic Framework using Auth0?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're using Ionic or Ionic 2, but here is a really good article to use auth0 (including G+) with Ionic 2 : http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-2-and-auth0/

Comment: Sorry if I couldn't paraphrase it clearly. This is all good but it uses inAppBrowser so the user has to enter their credentials but what I need is Google+ app based where the app takes over the sign in and returns control back to app